# Correct way to test if tested object is not null before assertion

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I write my first tests, and I want you ask, if that my testing is right. I need test if some object was updated after update method, so here is my test's structure:

```
@Test
public void myTest {
   // init myObj variable which I want test
   // myObjService is my service for my object which I've initialized in @Before tagged function
   MyObj myObj = myObjService.getById(465);

   // test if that variable is initialized, and it is not null
   Assert.assertNotNull(myObj);

   // update some properties of myObj
   myObj.setX(...);
   myObj.setY(...);
   ...

   // call update function which update obj in collection by Id of object
   myObjService.update(myObj);

   // get object with same id which should be with updated properties
   MyObj myUpdatedObj = myObjService.getById(465);

   // test that properties
   Assert.assertEquals(myObj.getX(), myUpdatedObj.getX());
   Assert.assertEquals(myObj.getY(), myUpdatedObj.getY());
   ...
}
```

Is that procedure correct or should I edit something?

Comment: First of all, I see two tests. Keep in mind, Given/When/Then.  Given an Id, When `myObjService.getById(465)`, Then `Assert.assertNotNull(myObj)`. You can split your tests.

Comment: @DjoryKrache Can you show my correct example? How I should split that, because I want be sure myObj is not null before that I will call its functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the null check at all? What benefits do you seek? Because:

1. You can explicitly control if the null is possible by preparing all the test data in the test itself.
2. If for some reason you cannot do this - still what you need from test is to clearly state what happened when it failed. You can easily find that out by the NPE in the stack trace. So I wouldn't blotter the tests with extra lines. Especially given that in your case null is more likely to happen due to a bug in test setup.

My recommendation would be to prepare all the data in the test itself:

```
public void updatesAllFieldsOfDog() {
    //creates object with random values
    Dog original = dao.createDog(Dog.random());
    //create new object with random fields and set the ID to the original
    //which effectively means - original object with all fields updated
    Dog updated = Dog.random().setId(original.getId());
    dao.updateDog(updated);
    Dog fromDb = dao.getDog(original.getId());
    //Method from Unitils that compares all the fields
    assertReflectionEquals(updated, fromDb);
}
```

Similar tests can be found [here](https://github.com/qala-io/java-course/blob/master/src/test/java/io/qala/javatraining/dao/HibernateDogDaoTest.java) if you're interested in the details.

Answer (score 1):

This procedure is missing a critical step of ensuring that the fields are not set to their new values at the beginning of the test.

Add these lines to the test:

```
MyObj myObj = myObjService.getById(465);
Assert.assertNotEquals("newValue1", myObj.getX());
Assert.assertNotEquals("newValue2", myObj.getY());
```

Comment: Ok, I've added this, and first step of checking null of tested object is correct? I here from my school mate I should  use some assume functions, what do you think?

Comment: @DenisStephanov yes, you are right, null check is definitely in order there. I am not sure about the “assume” functions in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can split it.

```
@Test
public void retreiveMyObjTest {
   // GIVEN
   Integer myObjId = 465;
   // WHEN
   MyObj myObj = myObjService.getById(465);
   // THEN
   Assert.assertNotNull(myObj);
   Assert.assertEquals(myObjId, myObj.getId());
   ...
}
@Test
public void updateMyObjTest {
   // GIVEN
   MyObj myObj = myObjService.getById(465);
   // WHEN
   myObj.setX(...);
   myObj.setY(...);
   myObjService.update(myObj);
   MyObj myUpdatedObj = myObjService.getById(465);
   // THEN
   Assert.assertEquals(myObj.getX(), myUpdatedObj.getX());
   Assert.assertEquals(myObj.getY(), myUpdatedObj.getY());
   ...
}
```

But in most of case, you cannot predict the ID 465 is in your database. You should find something more abstract for this or you should use another database only for test.